# couldn't understand output of grep with regular expression while using pipe

Tags: command-line, grep, regex, wildcards

As far as I know, while using regex with grep single quotes should be used otherwise the shell interpretet it as glob(wildcard) characters and performs a filename expansion, but in the below example, the shell is taking it as regex even though the search string is not in quotes.

```
sh-4.3$ ls                                                                                                                                                                      
main.sh  test1  test2  test3.sh  test34  test3a                                                                                                                                 
sh-4.3$ ls | grep test3y*                                                                                                                                                       
test3.sh                                                                                                                                                                        
test34                                                                                                                                                                          
test3a                                                                                                                                                                          
sh-4.3$
```

I couldn't get the reason as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That works because your expression `test3y*` doesn't match any filenames in the directory, so it isn't expanded into anything and is passed to `grep` literally making the regex valid (`y*` = `y` may occur zero or more times in that position).

You should still *always* quote your regex though!